# Caching reverse foreign key object in django admin display

Tags: foreign-keys, django-admin, django-queryset

I'm trying to fetch some different attribute from reverse foreign key object and show it on django admin list_display. But this current method will call the db queries multiple times

```
models.py:
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    ...
    def get_all_book(self):
        return self.book_set.all()

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    aaa = some field type
    bbb = some field type
    ...

admin.py:
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def book_aaa(obj):
        booklist = obj.get_all_book
        all_bookaaa = ",".join([k.aaa for k in booklist])
        return all_bookaaa
    def book_bbb(obj):
        booklist = obj.get_all_book
        all_bookbbb = ",".join([k.bbb for k in booklist])
        return all_bookbbb
    list_display = ('name', book_aaa, book_bbb)

admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)
```

Because I need to separate those book information in separate column, but if using this method, it might called "book_set.all()" queryset twice, which is very bad for the performance. Is there any correct method to implement this problem?

Comment: I just found a solution but kinda lame, by creating extra attribute to the obj and check whether the obj already has the attribute, if None then get_all_book, otherwise return it directly.

Answer (score 0):

By creating extra attribute to the object, and check whether the attribute exists or not.

```
def get_booklist(self, obj):
    if not hasattr(obj, 'booklist')
        obj.booklist = obj.get_all_book
    return obj
def book_aaa(self, obj):
    booklist = self.get_booklist(obj).booklist
    all_bookaaa = ",".join([k.aaa for k in booklist])
    return all_bookaaa
def book_bbb(self, obj):
    booklist = self.get_booklist(obj).booklist
    all_bookbbb = ",".join([k.bbb for k in booklist])
    return all_bookbbb
list_display = ('name', 'book_aaa', 'book_bbb')
```

Maybe this is not the best solution, but at least can prevent the queryset called multiple times.